# Extract json data in post request

Tags: python, classification, rest

I have **json** data and using this data as an input for the document classification model.
Here is the example of code where I create request based on json data:

```
import requests
data = {"id": "RequestID",
        "content":
             {
               "page1" : "content of page 1",
               "page2" : "content of page 2"
              }
        }
response = requests.post("{}".format("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict"), json = data)
print(str(response.json()))
```

But as a response I got the following error:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is the code which makes classification and sends back as a response document class:

```
 Create an API endpoint
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        value = data["content"]
        value=value.rstrip()
         ...
         pred_str=doc_class
         ...

        # return the result back
        resp = jsonify({"status": 200,'body': pred_str,"headers" : {
                        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
                        }
                        })
        return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Any idea what could be wrong and why this error?

Comment: ```response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", json.dumps(data))``` try this

Comment: Why are you formating a string into an empty string... you can simply write it directly...

Comment: with json.dumps(data)) I got the same error. Interesting is that when I use the following json :

data = {"id": "RequestID",
            "content": "content of page 1" }
everything is fine

Comment: You need to use one-dimensional dictionary here (key and value)... As alternative you can use a list of tuples ```[('key', 'value1'), ('key', 'value2')]```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you mean something like this :
data = {"id": "RequestID",  "page1" : "content of page 1", "page2" : "content of page 2" }
That could be solution but than  I need merge all contents in one value for classification

Comment: Yes, you need to do something like this - ```data = {"id": "value1", "page1": "content1", "page2": "content2"}```.  Also you can do this like this ```data = {"id": "value1", "content": ["content1", "content2"]}```

Comment: I tried this second structure and error is the same
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
 I was sure that this will work :)
ata = {"id": "RequestID", "content": ["content of Page 1",
                "content of Page 2"
        ]
        }

Comment: I can't understand the reason for this error. When I try to extract content for this tag (outside this classification procedure) everything works well. For example load data and then value = data ["content"]. But in classification procedure I get the error